# Optimal Number of Entries for a Contest of Skill...

Tags: probability, decision-theory

**Objective:**  I'm looking for the optimal number of unique entries in a contest of skill with monetary prizes.

**Description:**  The contests vary from as little as 20 entries up to 10,000+ entries.  You can enter an unlimited amount of entries.  Within each entry, there are 9 slots that can be filled with variables.  Each slot has a unique set of variables that cannot be used in any other slot.  The unique variables for each slot may number from about 2-30 depending on the contest.  Once you enter your chosen variables in the slots, the variables score points based upon real-life events.  Some slots traditionally score many more points than other slots.  The entry with the highest amount of points wins.  Prize money is split in the event of a tie score.

**Assumptions:** I am an above average player.  When facing similar competition, assume I can win 57% of the time (if playing in a fifty/fifty contest where half of the entrants win prize money).  The contest has exactly 10,055 entries.  The entry fee is $2.  The prize distribution is detailed as follows (minus 10.5% entry fee going to contest organizers):

**Prizes:**

**1st:** $2,000;
**2nd:** 1,200;
**3rd:** 800;
**4th:** 500;
**5th:** 350;
**6th:** 300;
**7th:** 250;
**8th:** 200;
**9th:** 180;
**10th**: 160;
**11th:** 150;
**12th:** 140;
**13th:** 130;
**14th:** 120;
**15th:** 110;
**16th:** 100;
**17th - 18th:** 90;
**19th - 20th:** 80;
**21st - 22nd:** 70;
**23rd - 25th:** 60;
**26th - 28th:** 50;
**29th - 35th:** 40;
**36th - 50th:** 30;
**51st - 60th:** 20;
**61st - 75th:** 18;
**76th - 100th:** 16;
**101st - 200th:** 14;
**201st - 400th:** 12;
**401st - 600th:** 10;
**601st - 800th:** 8;
**801st - 1050th:** 6

**Discussion:** I have an above average understanding of probability (but that's not really saying much), so I've gotten as far as running a simulation (the paper and pencil kine) with 10 entries and a 10 dollar entry fee (1st-$50, 2nd-30, 3rd-20).  Internet research suggests, and my paper simulations concur, that using 2 or more of the exact same entries will always result in a negative expected value (EV).

I then tried to run the simulation with two different entries.  There seem to be 44 unique possibilities. I added up the prize money; then, I multiplied by 1/44.  I took this answer then subtracted the $20 in entry fees.  The result was an expected value of 45 cents.  Is this correct?

Assuming my math is correct, I have no clue how to apply it to the contests with a much higher number of entries to find the optimal number of unique entries I should submit.  I don't really know how to translate my assumed 57% success rate in one contest to another contest.  I also don't know if it's best to have completely unique entries or just slightly unique entries (it seems that I should diversify my entries and make them as unique as possible while still maximizing points scored).

Any help, guidance, or tips are very much appreciated.  Have a great day.

P.S. If you know the contests I'm talking about, please don't refer to them by name.

P.S.S. I asked this question on math.stackexchange yesterday, but nobody answered.

Comment: From reading this it does not sound that the "slots" and "variables" and "trdaitionally scoring more" and whatnot have any influence. It seems,  You want us to estmiate the distribution of your exact ranking in a random contess based on the sole information that the probabilty that you rank above the median is $0.57$?

Comment: I recognize what this is and if you have a skill advantage over the other players what is most important isn't how many buy-ins you blow through, but the effective stack size a re-buy gives you in relation to the rest of the field. The bigger the stack size, the better the opportunity you have to apply your superior knowledge/skill. Thus, re-buy as many times as your effective stack size is favorable versus the average stack in the tournament in relation to your knowledge/skill advantage..

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen,

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen   when you don't know the answer, it's hard to know what you're exactly looking for.  although, entries with overlapping variables seems it should have some relevance (maybe the more differentiated the entries, the more they approximate the ideal?), but i think it is secondary to the main question of the optimal number of entries.  because the contests are not random, i don't know.  i'm guessing that randomness is just an assumption that needs to be made.  i think your paraphrase is accurate if the "distribution of your exact ranking" will reveal the optimal number of entries.

Comment: @Vincent - can this be quantified at all?  i'm not sure what "stack size" is?  is it the number of total entries?  the estimate is relevant because at some point the law of diminishing returns kicks in.  i'm trying to figure out where that is.  i also have to manage my money.  if 10 entries don't increase my odds substantially, then maybe my money should be better allocated to contests where the probability is in my favor.

Comment: Your question was nearly identical to that of a poker tournament with re-buys so I assumed incorrectly that it must have been such a tournament. The idea remains the same despite it not being a poker tournament. You could do the math on your tournament sure, but it isn't really necessary I don't think. Keep it simple. If you have a 57% chance to win means your odds are $1.32:1$. As long as you're getting better than $1.32:1$ on your money keep re-buying. This obviously doesn't take every variable into account but over-complicating it won't change your optimal play by much.

Comment: @Vincent - okay.  thanks for trying to help me.